# Have only one button submit form?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have inherited a project and there is a form with 3 buttons:

```
<input type="submit" id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_back" value="Make Changes" name="ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$back" onClick="history.back();">
<input type="submit" id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_preview" value="View Outside" name="ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$preview">
<input type="submit" id="ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_submit" value="Send Card" name="ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$submit">
```

How do I make it so, that only 1 button actually submits the form to another page for processing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change all the other ones to `type="button"`

Answer (score 1):

Change the input **type="button"** instead of **type="submit"**. These kind of look like ASP controls, so find and replace these form buttons with a plain button, unbound.

Answer (score 1):

By not letting them be submit buttons. Use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.